# Building a Raspberry Pi Cross Compiler

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

So I'm following this tutorial online to build a cross compiler for the Raspberry PI.  [Tutorial](http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/)

When executing the command 'ct-ng build' to prepare the compiler, I'm getting:

> insn-opinit.h: No such file or directory

I'm using GCC v4.8.1 Linaro with non-parallel builds.  There seems to be a patch for GCC available, but I have no idea where to start with this.  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the following tutorial and was able to get it working.  This was much easier than the original way that I was going about this.  [Tutorial](http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest is to use [biicode](https://www.biicode.com/), it automatically sets up the cross compiling environment and sends generated binaries to the raspberry-pi. It can also automate cmake generation.
To install the cross-compiler and other required tools (gcc, cmake) you just have to install it and run `bii setup:rpi`